# fstat() does not work as expected inside a preloaded mmap() system call

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, kernel, posix

I am trying to get the device minor and major numbers from `fstat()`. The call to `fstat()` is done inside a preloaded `mmap()` system call:

```
// preload.so
// compile with:
// gcc  -ldl -Wall -shared -fPIC -o preload.so -D_GNU_SOURCE preload.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#if __GNUC__ >= 4
#define PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#else
#define PUBLIC
#endif

PUBLIC void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset) {
    printf("preload\n");

    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)
        printf("fstat() failed\n");
    else 
        printf("%u %u\n", major(sb.st_rdev), minor(sb.st_rdev));

    typedef void*(*mmap_t)(void *, size_t, int, int, int, off_t);
    mmap_t o_mmap = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mmap");
    return (*o_mmap)(start, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);
}
```

The above library can then intercept any mmap() system call from any given program:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so ./my_prog
```

Why do I keep obtaining 0 and 0 as major and minor number, although `my_prog` attempts to `mmap()` a device after opening a real device node?

Is there any way to obtain the major and minor numbers from within the preloaded mmap() system call without any other informations except the arguments passed to the function itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmap() will be called by a lot of other code as well, e.g.

- To load/map shared libraries.
- To obtain anonymous memory (e.g. malloc() might call mmap to obtain more memory)

In the first case, the mmap()'ed file is just a regular file, and will have have a minor/major of 0.
In the second case, the fd passed in is not a valid fd - the app should pass -1 as the fd, but it might not..

You're likely seeing these mmap() calls from the runtime and indirectly from other
library calls your application does, not just the mmap() call of a device that your app does.

On e.g. Linux/glibc, and possibly other systems as well, I'd presume an `mmap()` call could be compiled to call `mmap64()` instead, depending on compiler flags that's used to enable large file support. You might need to intercept `mmap64()` as well as `mmap()`

It's unclear what you're really trying to do, but you could

- check that fd is not -1
- check that the flags does not contain MAP_ANONYMOUS
- then perform fstat.
- check the `struct stat`.st_mode for S_ISCHR() or S_ISBLK() (see the stat man page) to know if mmap()  was for a device file
- if the `sb.st_rdev` is for the major/minor number your interested in, take action.